# Using contains inside when clause for Spark Data Frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following working statement for a DS and DF:

```
val ds2 = ds.withColumn("new_telnum", 
             when(expr("substring(telnum,1,2)") === "91" || 
                  expr("substring(telnum,1,2)") === "01", 
                  expr("substring(telnum,3,length(telnum)-2)"))
            .otherwise(col("telnum")))
```

But, I cannot seem to convert the `when` expression to use a `List` with the `contains` construct to replace the `or`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using [isin](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@isin(list:Any*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), like in the following example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val ds = Seq(
  ("012223334444"),
  ("1112223333"),
  ("913334445555"),
  ("884445556666")
).toDF("telnum").as[(String)]

val codeList = List("91", "01")

ds.withColumn( "new_telnum", when( substring($"telnum", 1, 2).isin(codeList: _*),
    expr("substring(telnum, 3, length(telnum) - 2)")
  ).otherwise($"telnum")
).show
// +------------+------------+
// |      telnum|  new_telnum|
// +------------+------------+
// |012223334444|  2223334444|
// |  1112223333|  1112223333|
// |913334445555|  3334445555|
// |884445556666|884445556666|
// +------------+------------+
```

Comment: You beaut. When to use what then? I.e. isin vs. contains?

Comment: Using the same example dataset, `contains` could be used as condition `$"telnum".contains("91") || $"telnum".contains("01")` in the `when` clause – in a way similar to what you originally have.  To check the value of a given column against a list of items, I'd say `isin` is the way to go.

Comment: Agree. I think there is a tendency to overuse .contains.